# Ajax calling to show data

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am very new in web developing. In my database, I have the table named customers. There are two columns named customer name, and customer address. in my interface I have a field where I can search for the customers. in interface, there is another field named "customer address". My aim is to fill the field customer address no sooner had the customer name is selected.

#### This is my view file

```
<tr>
    <th valign="top" style="text-align:right">Customer Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
    <td><input type='text' id="customer_name" class="text_box" autocomplete="off" name='customer_name' value="<?= set_value('customer_name', $customer_name) ?>" /><?= form_error('customer_name', '<span class="error">', '</span>') ?>
        <div class="jcustomer_list"></div>
        <input name="customer_id" value="" type="hidden" class="customer_id">
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th valign="top" style="text-align:right">Customer Address:&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
    <td><input type='text' id="customer_adress" class="text_box" autocomplete="off" name='customer_adress' value="<?= $_REQUEST['customer_adress']  ?>" /><?= form_error('customer_adress', '<span class="error">', '</span>') ?>
        <div class="jcustomer_list"></div>
        <input name="customer_id" value="" type="hidden" class="customer_id">
    </td>
</tr>
```

#### This is my AJAX class

```
bind:function(){

    $j('.jcustomer_list').find('li').unbind('click');
    $j('.jcustomer_list').find('li').bind('click',function(){

        $j('#customer_name').val($j(this).attr('title'));
        //$j('#customer_address').val($j(this).attr('title'));

        $j('.customer_id').val($j(this).attr('rel'));
        var cid=$j(this).attr('rel');
        customer.getPreviousBalance(cid);   
        customer.getCustmerAddress(cid);
        $j('.jcustomer_list').css('display','none');
    });
},

getCustmerAddress:function(cid){
    $j.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:base_url+'ajax/load_customer_address',
        data:{
            cid:cid
        },
        //here a success function must be added but I am not being able to this.

        error:function(a,b,c){
        },
    });
    }
}
```

#### This is my common helper function

```
public static function get_customer_address($cid) {
    $CI = &get_instance();
    $c = sql::row("customers", "customer_id='$cid'", "customer_address");
    return $c;      
}
```

Comment: where is ```success``` in ajax?? You need to write the code in success.

Answer (score 0):

Your script looks like you have added extra **}** bracket & here is the AJAX Code should be.
I am assuming your controller function return the correct result.

```
$j.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:base_url+'ajax/load_customer_address',
    data:{
        cid:cid
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {              
         console.log(response);
        // Your data came here   
    },
    error:function(a,b,c){
    },
});
```